# Why is the legend in my Dojo charting chart not showing the colours?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using dojo charting and for some reason the legend for my chart is showing x's instead of the colours.

Here is my code:

```
dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.blue");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.widget.Legend");
dojo.require("dojox.layout.FloatingPane");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.MiamiNice");
dojo.require("dojo.colors");
makeCharts = function(){
var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart");

chart1.addPlot("default", {type: "StackedColumns", markers: true, tension:3, shadows: {dx: 2, dy: 2, dw: 2}});
chart1.addAxis("x",{labels: [{value: 1 , text: '18-Mar'}, {value: 2 , text: '19-Mar'}, {value: 3 , text: '20-Mar'}, {value: 4 , text: '21-Mar'}, {value: 5 , text: '22-Mar'}, {value: 6 , text: '23-Mar'}]});
chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical:true});

chart1.addSeries("Four", [196,209,77,218,48,243]);

chart1.addSeries("One", [266,158,131,228,217,262]);

chart1.addSeries("Three", [296,214,267,80,40,225]);

chart1.addSeries("Two", [207,264,115,227,193,27]);

chart1.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.MiamiNice);
var legend = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({chart: chart1, horizontal: true}, "legend");

chart1.render();
}

dojo.addOnLoad(makeCharts);
```

As I said the Chart displays perfectly but, the Legend doesn't have any colours on it.

Comment: I thought that was a sad face at first, but no - you have a ); hanging out of your code block.

Comment: fixed javascript missing function declaration.

Comment: hi, is this working like in Google Finance with the zoom and pan functions and etc?

Comment: No Static charts from data They are very pretty though http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_themes.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found out the Issue, the Legend has to be declared after the chart is rendered.

Many thanks to the people at #dojo for their pointing me at more examples that helped me notice this.

Comment: I read this Q via RSS, went to answer that you need to swap 2 lines, and found that you already found it out. :-) In general #dojo and the dojo forum are right places to ask dojo-specific questions. SO is good for generic questions.

Comment: Yeah ttrenka and I spent a few minutes looking at it before I noticed that I'd got them the wrong way round.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "the Legend has to be declared after the chart is rendered" you are saying, call chart1.render(); and then create the legend with something like: new Legend({chart: chart1}, "legend");